# Vectorizing artwork and finding source of an image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, logo

So, hello all here at stackexchange.

I need help.

My client wants me to make a logo around this image.
But he sent me a jpeg despite apparently "knowing" how to convert to vector or svg for me to make my life easier.
[image]

Live trace is too messy of a method for this, and I know I should be able to export paths to illustrator from ps, but it seems to only transplant a blank image. I used to know a method in school to make this easier, but to make the file editable as is the only method I tried was to magic wand bits and export piece by piece by piece, or tracing it outright.

**Preferably, I'd like this to be a layered document, saved as vector. Are there any possible methods of conversion?**

Also, is there a whatthefont for images? This is clearly a jpeg of a nice vector but I have no idea where he got it, and I think I've asked before.

Comment: It's a very simple drawing; you could just recreate it manually, shouldn't take more than twenty minutes at the most. More importantly, though, does your client have **permission** to use this artwork for their logo? If not, you'd be aiding them in plagiarism by making the logo. If your client does have permission to use the artwork, they should also have a vector version available for you—the _original_, mind, not one they made from the JPEG.

Comment: I thought that might be the case if this was not stock, I guess I need to ask him. However I did end up creating a similar logo from scratch that is original. 
I definitely can I just very much dislike rebuilding something.

Comment: A quick [Google image search](https://www.google.com/search?q=lufthansa+chatbot&newwindow=1&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjIsYO837bUAhWL7IMKHYMqBGoQ_AUICygC&biw=1368&bih=776) will show that it's Lufthansa's work. so it would most likely be ©

Answer (score 1):

try visiting http://www.flaticon.com u can find this types of artworks over there for free. but u must credit the author if you don't want any legal trouble in future(i would recommend you give credit just for the peace of mind if you wish to use their art). or just trace the artwork using pen tool I don't think it will take more than 45 minutes to recreate. But if you are doing this for a client I would highly recommend that you create something on your own. and if the client insists on using that graphic only you should warn him of the consequences and make sure you will not be held responsible.

Answer (score 0):

The comments already show that the image cannot be taken without a written permission. It can be impossible to get it. Additionally it's not easy to believe that any smaller business is well presented by an image taken from big enterprise's web page.

But if that lady somehow well fits to your customer's purposes, you should consider to represent her otherwise. As a bonus there opens also possiblities to lift up some essential, maybe in original only weakly recognizable features.

The following example (a top wiew) of representing is only a quess because I have no idea, what in reality is essential:

[image]

About vectorization: No need to do it, you must draw your own.